# Java ArrayList Sort on the basis of dynamic objects fields?

Tags: java

I am getting a issue i have below code

```
public void columnsList(List<TableRecord> records){

    for(TableRecord record : records){
        Table table = record.getTable();
        //Do sort here on stampDate
        Field[] fields = table.fields();
        for(Field field : fields){
            field.getName();
            record.getValue(field);

        }
    }

}
```

and `records` object contain Object of different class type

```
List<TableRecord> records = new List<TableRecord>();
records.add(new AddressRecord());
records.add(new CityRecord());
records.add(new UserRecord());
```

Now how i need to sort them by `stampDate` variable which is in each class how can we do it when we have different classes in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the classes write your comparator( `Comparator<Object>`), that will try to find the field stampDate and compare them. Than use it for sorting the list.
Comparator implementation:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;


public class StampDateComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

@Override
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

    try {
        Date d1 = (Date) o1.getClass().getDeclaredField("stampDate").get(o1);
        Date d2 = (Date) o2.getClass().getDeclaredField("stampDate").get(o2);
        return compare(d1, d2);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Missing variable stampDate");
    }catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("stampDate is not a Date");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        //shoud not happen
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: @Hariom But you can mark it as correct answer ;-). Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Yes i will one more question I have to sort on the basis of date will this code do that

Comment: `Collections.sort(records, new StampDateComparator);` does it. Of course assuming the stampDate is java.util.Date.

Comment: What is records here its a List?

Comment: Yes, please look at java.util.Collections

Answer (score 2):

If your code above is correct, that means `AddressRecord`, `CityRecord` and `UserRecord` all extend `TableRecord`:

```
class AddressRecord extends TableRecord {
    // other fields and methods here
}
class CityRecord extends TableRecord {
    // other fields and methods here
}
class UserRecord extends TableRecord {
    // other fields and methods here
}
```

You only have to write a `Comparator` for this class. It should look something like this:

```
class TableRecord {
    private Date timeStamp;

    public Date getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }
// other fields and methods here
}

class RecordStampDateComparator implements Comparator<TableRecord>{

    public int compare(TableRecord tr1, TableRecord tr2) {
        Date tr1Date = tr1.getTimeStamp();
        Date tr2Date = tr2.getTimeStamp();   
        return tr1Date.compareTo(tr2Date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write abstract class **Record** with protected field **stampDate**, that implements **Comparable** and override **compareTo** method.

```
public abstract class Record implements Comparable<Record> {
    protected Date stampDate;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Record anotherRecord){
        return this.stampDate.compareTo(anotherRecord.stampDate);
    }
}
```

Then extend this class with your record classes:

```
public class AddressRecord extends Record{
...
}

public class CityRecord extends Record{
...
}

public class UserRecord extends Record{
...
}
```

Comment: Not quite right.[Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is more suitable in this case, since [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) imposes a `natural ordering`.

Comment: @aUserHimself, maybe that's not quite right, but this example is still  usable. Let the TS choose =)

Comment: It doesn't really matter that `TableRecord` cannot be modified, you can use `Comparator`. The main problem is whether you can extend it to define `AddressRecord`, `CityRecord` and `UserRecord` or not.

Comment: @Hariom, so? You can import this class. You also can do that:

   **public class UserRecord extends com.example.Record**

Answer (score 0):

Use following Comparator class on List.

```
class TableRecordCompare implements Comparator<TableRecord>{
     if(TableRecord instanceof AddressRecord){
       // return compareTo for sample data of address.
     }
     else if(TableRecord instanceof CityRecord){
     // return compareTo for sample data of CityRecord.
      }
     else{
     // return compareTo for sample data of UserRecord.
    }

}
```

Comment: 'else if(TableRecord inteseof CityRecord)' is not possible here can be 100 of class i have to compare